# How can I make window management easy for a toddler?

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I've got a spare old computer my toddler can use paint programs on.

Is there a way to really simplify window management, e.g. one maximized app per desktop ?

At the moment she keeps un-maximizing apps by accident.

It would be good to just one app at a time.

Are the extensions to the desktop shell that will simplify this stuff ?